# How to convert string to datetime(datetime) in same format?

Tags: c#, datetime

Here I want to convert date into string using `tostring` but when I convert it back, (string to datetime), the format is different.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string cc = "2014/12/2";
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(cc);
        Console.WriteLine(dt);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

expected output:
    2014/12/2
But I get:
    12/2/2014

Comment: What's the wrong with current code?

Comment: it's showing 12/2/2014 but I want in 2014/12/2

Comment: A date is displayed in the default format, unless you format it explicitly using tostring. Many answers are correct, but you say it's not what you want. Either your question is very unclear or you don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for all I am unable to accept all the answers but all almost all are  correct answers but which is worked for me I am giving to vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string DateString = "06/20/1990";
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true); 
DateTime dateVal = DateTime.ParseExact(DateString, "yyyy-MM-dd", culture);
```

This will be your desire output

***udpated***

```
string DateString = "20/06/1990";;
                IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
                DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(DateString,"dd/mm/yyyy",culture);
                dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: hi it's showing  error:String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: @stpdevi what u are passing into this?

Comment: nothing I had excuted ur code as it is but it showing above error

Answer (score 1):

Call `ToString` with format provided when you convert `DateTime` instance back to `string`:

```
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString(@"yyyy/M/d");
```

Comment: sry I want in reverse conversion to datetime with below format yyyy/M/dd

Comment: I want to use datetime not tostring conversion

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "ddMMyyyy", 
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
    string cc = "2014/12/2";
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(cc);
    string str = dt.ToString("yyyy/M/dd"); // 2014/12/02 as you wanted
    Console.WriteLine(str);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
string formattedDate= dt.ToString("yyyy/M/d");
```

For reverse you can use

```
DateTime newDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2014/05/22", "yyyy/M/d", null);
```

So if your expected output is like : 2014/12/2 
you have to use

newDate.ToString("yyyy/M/d");

Comment: sry I want in reverse conversion to datetime with below format yyyy/M/dd

Comment: sry it giving 12.2.2014 output

Answer (score 1):

As you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `DateTime.ToString()` uses [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to decide how to format its output (`CurrentCulture` of type `CultureInfo` provides information on how to format dates, currency, calendar etc. It is called *locale* in C++).

Thus, the simlplest solution as suggested by previous answers, is to use an overload of `ToString()` which accepts a format string, effectively overriding the `CurrentCulture` info:

```
dt.ToString(@"yyyy/MM/dd");
```

More on datetime formatting can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: my problem is here in my dbd datatype is datetime so I should add in same format without conversion to tostring

Comment: @stpdevi - under the hood, `Console.WriteLine(dt)` calls the default `dt.ToString()`. It does so for any non-string parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple, You just need to use date pattern during display

```
string cc = "2014/12/2";
string datePatt = @"yyyy/MM/d";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(cc);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString(datePatt));
```